# c# string of numbers to array of two value numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Hello I am new to C# and trying to learn. I require some help if anybody is able to help I would really appreciate it.

So I am making a program that takes lottery numbers from a website and compares them with the user imputed numbers. I have managed to this but the problem I have is that I get the numbers as a string like this `384826453514` then I compare the string with he user input, so as you can tell if I enter `3 8 4 6 5 1` its says win!

How can I parse or change that string to an array of Integers that have two values like this `int[38][48][26][45][35][14]` (I know this is not an actually array).

Any help would be very much appreciated even to point me in the right direction.

Comment: how do you know if 384826... is 38, 48, 26 ... or 38, 4, 8, 2, 6 ... ?

Comment: Should it really say "win" if the numbers are `38 48 26 45 35 14` and the user inputs `38 46 51` (the example you have provided)?

Comment: Amit this is the problem i am having. C.Evenhuis no in this case it should not , that was just an example of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Being unable to uniquely identify the separator seems like a very serious problem to me. I would start from solving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, 4 would be entered as 04 , and all numbers have 2 long, you can do this :

```
var input = "38482645351404";
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length/2).Select(i => int.Parse(input.Substring(i*2, 2))).ToArray();
```

Comment: That did it thanks you, I will have do more research on substrings , thank you very much for your time.